# Suddenly Tabularray stopped working

Tags: tabularray

After recent update of MiKTeX installation `tabularray` stopped working. It throw errors

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \g__tblr_defined_hdash_styles_prop 
                                              
l.1089 ...al:Nn \g__tblr_defined_hdash_styles_prop
                                                  
?
```

A simple test MWE:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

File list is the following:

```
File List*
  beamer.cls    2024/01/06 v3.71 A class for typesetting presentations
beamerbasemodes.sty    
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
beamerbasedecode.sty    
   iftex.sty    2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
beamerbaseoptions.sty    
  keyval.sty    2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
geometry.cfg
 pgfmath.sty    
  pgfrcs.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
pgfmath.code.tex
  size11.clo    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
graphicx.sty    2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
  pgfsys.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
  xcolor.sty    2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
mathcolor.ltx
pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi-ltx.sty    2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
hyperref.sty    2024-01-20 v7.01h Hypertext links for LaTeX
kvsetkeys.sty    2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
 nameref.sty    2023-11-26 v2.56 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
gettitlestring.sty    2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   puenc.def    2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  bitset.sty    2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
atveryend-ltx.sty    2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend packa
ge
with kernel methods
rerunfilecheck.sty    2022-07-10 v1.10 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    
beamerbasefont.sty    
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2020/01/31
scrlfile.sty    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)
scrlfile-hook.sty    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)
 scrlogo.sty    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (logo)
beamerbasetranslator.sty    
translator.sty    2021-05-31 v1.12d Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
beamerbasemisc.sty    
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    
beamerbasetitle.sty    
beamerbasesection.sty    
beamerbaseframe.sty    
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    
beamerbaseframesize.sty    
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    
beamerbasecolor.sty    
beamerbasenotes.sty    
beamerbasetoc.sty    
beamerbasetemplates.sty    
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    
beamerbaseboxes.sty    
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    
enumerate.sty    2023/07/04 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    
beamerbasenavigationsymbols.tex
beamerbasetheorems.sty    
 amsmath.sty    2023/05/13 v2.17o AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2020/05/29 v2.20.6
beamerbasethemes.sty    
beamerthemedefault.sty    
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    
tabularray.sty    2023-03-01 v2023A Typeset tabulars and arrays with LaTeX3
   expl3.sty    2024-02-13 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-pdftex.def    2024-01-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
test-winedt.out
test-winedt.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict    
ninecolors.sty    2022-02-13 v2022D Select colors with proper color contrast
  xparse.sty    2024-02-13 L3 Experimental document command parser
 ***********
```

Do anyone has similar experiences? Before updating MiKTeX they works fine. I do not remember which packages was updated, I only remember that among them was `siunitx`, and one named something `miktex.<...>`, and if this is somehow connected with above error.

Comment: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2024-February/049989.html

Comment: the updated tabularry has already been sent to ctan so it should be fixed soon, but the workaround is at the link sam carter gave

Comment: Your example works fine with `tabularray 2024-02-16`. If you don't want to wait until miktex distributes the new version, you could switch to texlive, which already has it.

Comment: The error was due to variables set before declaring them. Changes in `expl3` code now strongly require that `prop` variables are declared before being set. Of course, the recommendation to declare variables before using them has always been active.

Comment: MiKTeX just provide new version of `tabularray` package (version 2024A from 2024-02-16) which works fine. Thank you to all for valuable comments and especially to Christian Schenk for providing it so fast!